# When was System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[]) added?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Some people using my app seem to be getting

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 
'System.Object System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke
    (System.Delegate, System.Object[])'
```

Does anyone know in what version of the framework this overload was added, is it safe to use?(its not marked deprecated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following Methods were added on 3.5 SP1 to the Dispatcher class

```
BeginInvoke(Delegate, array[]()[]), 
BeginInvoke(Delegate, DispatcherPriority, array[]()[]), 
Invoke(Delegate, array[]()[]), 
Invoke(Delegate, TimeSpan, array[]()[]), 
Invoke(Delegate, TimeSpan, DispatcherPriority, array[]()[]), 
Invoke(Delegate, DispatcherPriority, array[]()[])
```

Check out the following link:[MSDN-Dispatcher-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Got it too... soooo annoying.

Simply use:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, ...[REST OF PARAMS]);
```

This overload doesn't appear in the IntelliSense, but it compiles perfectly and works both on 3.5 and 3.5SP1

PROFIT!!